# I'm trying to begin programming in Swift, but Code Signing Error

Tags: ios, code-signing

I'm trying to code in Swift, but it keeps telling me that there is a Code Signing Error and I don't have a developer account - Is there any way I can run code without paying the developer fee? 
I'm on the version 6.3.2 of XCode

Comment: Yep, you can do that in the simulator.
At the WWDC they announced you'll be able to run on the device without being a member of the program as well, I'm not familiar with that yet, but I think that'll be with Xcode 7.
Also, if you are serious about it, $100 is not a lot.

Comment: @EmilioPelaez Is there a way for me to try coding/run without paying before XCode 7 comes out? I used to be able to run programs without this error. At the moment, I am just trying it out and unsure of whether or not I am sticking with this - I still might try Android as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Is there any way I can run code without paying the developer fee

Absolutely. It costs nothing to Build and Run your code when the destination is a Simulator. This has always been free, and remains free.

And in the future (Xcode 7?) it will be possible even to Build and Run on your device for free.

Comment: How do I set destination to be a Simulator?

Comment: Product > Destination > [...]